# What is the origin of an arbitrary basis?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose I say

Let $S$ be a basis of $R^2$:

$$S = \{u_1, u_2\} = \{(1, 2), (3, 5)\} $$

How do I find the origin of this basis?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "origin of this basis".  A basis  for $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a pair of vectors, neither of which is a multiple of the other (linear independence), that can generate any other vector by linear combination (spanning).

Comment: Perhaps you are thinking of a coordinate system?  In any case picking a basis for $\mathbb{R}^2$ does not change the "origin", which is $(0,0)$ in any coordinate system.

Comment: @hardmath Huh? So the origin is `(0,0)` in the coordinate system with basis `(1, 0), (0, 1)` and also for the coordinate system with the basis `(1,2), (3, 5)` (as well as every possible other one)?

Comment: Yes, $0u + 0v$ is the zero vector, regardless of basis vectors $u,v$.

Comment: I find that hard to understand. Every point other than $(0,0)$ is translated to be consistent with the new basis. What happens to the point $(0.00001, 0.00001)$? Does it jump drastically from the origin to the new basis location?

Comment: Dear Imray, The process of changing coordinates with respect to the new basis is continuous, so a point like $(.00001,.00001),$ whose coordinates are small with respect to the original basis, will have coordinates in the new basis that are also small.  (You can check this directly if you like.)  Regards,

Answer (score 4):

There is no "jump" from one origin to any "new basis location".  The origin (zero vector) is the same "location" and is represented the same unique way with respect to any basis of a vector space.

In your example, the linear combination $0\cdot(1,2) + 0\cdot(3,5) = 0\cdot(1,0) + 0\cdot(0,1)$ gives the same result $(0,0)$ regardless of what basis for $\mathbb{R}^2$ is chosen.  So the coordinates of the origin with respect to any *basis* of a vector space are always zero coordinates, whether in two-dimensions or another vector space.

---

The issue of what happens to the "origin" may be better understood if we consider what happens to nonzero vectors in "translating" coordinate representations from one basis to another.

When asking "What happens to the point $(0.00001,0.00001)$?", we need to clear up any confusion about the notation for points in $\mathbb{R}^2$.  With respect to the *standard basis* for $\mathbb{R}^2$, these coordinates represent a point on the line $y=x$ in the Cartesian plane.

There are two computations that can be done if a new (nonstandard) basis is chosen.  Ordinarily the choice of *new* basis has to be described in terms the standard basis, and I think that's what we mean if we take $S = \{(1,2),(3,5)\}$ to be a different basis.  The vectors of this basis $S$ are given in terms of standard basis coordinates.

The two computations are then:

(1) How do I "translate" a point's standard coordinates into coordinates for the nonstandard basis, say $S$ as a case in point?

(2) How do I "translate" a representation in coordinates for the nonstandard basis into the standard coordinates *for the same point*?

Combining these two operations lets us "translate" coordinates for a point in any basis to coordinates for the same point in any other basis.  As a practical matter, if the standard coordinates for the nonstandard basis vectors are known (as they are for $S$ in particular), then computation (2) is pretty easy (just take a linear combination) and computation (1) may be slightly challenging (because it requires solving a system of linear equations to get the "new" coordinates).